# Treafik Let's encrypt simplest example on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, lets-encrypt, traefik

I am trying to work on simplest possible [example](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/kubernetes-kitchen/tree/master/gcp/task-004-traefik/traefik-2.2/part3-traefik-whoami-lets-encrypt) of implementing let's encrypt with Traefik on GKE using this [article](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/user-guides/crd-acme/). I have made some changes to suit my requirement but I am unable to get the ACME certificate.

What I have done so far

- Run the following command and create all the resource objects except ingress-route

```sh
$ kubectl apply -f 00-resource-crd-definition.yml,05-traefik-rbac.yml,10-service-account.yaml,15-traefik-deployment.yaml,20-traefik-service.yaml,25-whoami-deployment.yaml,30-whoami-service.yaml
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/ingressroutes.traefik.containo.us created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/middlewares.traefik.containo.us created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/ingressroutetcps.traefik.containo.us created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/tlsoptions.traefik.containo.us created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/traefikservices.traefik.containo.us created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/traefik-ingress-controller created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/traefik-ingress-controller created
serviceaccount/traefik-ingress-controller created
deployment.apps/traefik created
service/traefik created
deployment.apps/whoami created
service/whoami created
```

- Get the IP of the Traefik Service exposed as Load Balancer

```sh
$ kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                                     AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.109.0.1      <none>         443/TCP                                     6h16m
traefik      LoadBalancer   10.109.15.230   34.69.16.102   80:32318/TCP,443:32634/TCP,8080:32741/TCP   70s
whoami       ClusterIP      10.109.14.91    <none>         80/TCP                                      70s
```

- Create a DNS record for this IP

```sh
$ nslookup k8sacmetest.gotdns.ch
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   k8sacmetest.gotdns.ch
Address: 34.69.16.102
```

- Create the resource ingress-route

```sh
$ kubectl apply -f 35-ingress-route.yaml
ingressroute.traefik.containo.us/simpleingressroute created
ingressroute.traefik.containo.us/ingressroutetls created
```

- Logs of traefik

```sh
time="2020-04-25T20:10:31Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from flags."
time="2020-04-25T20:10:32Z" level=error msg="subset not found for default/whoami" providerName=kubernetescrd ingress=simpleingressroute namespace=default
time="2020-04-25T20:10:32Z" level=error msg="subset not found for default/whoami" providerName=kubernetescrd ingress=ingressroutetls namespace=default
time="2020-04-25T20:10:52Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"k8sacmetest.gotdns.ch\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [k8sacmetest.gotdns.ch]: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[k8sacmetest.gotdns.ch] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem), url: \n" routerName=default-ingressroutetls-08dd2bb9eecaa72a6606@kubernetescrd rule="Host(`k8sacmetest.gotdns.ch`) && PathPrefix(`/tls`)" providerName=default.acme
```

What i have acheived

- Traefik Dashboard

[link](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/kubernetes-kitchen/blob/master/gcp/task-004-traefik/traefik-2.2/part3-traefik-whoami-lets-encrypt/.ReadMe_images/dashboard.png)

- Whoami with notls

[link](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/kubernetes-kitchen/blob/master/gcp/task-004-traefik/traefik-2.2/part3-traefik-whoami-lets-encrypt/.ReadMe_images/whoami-server-notls.png)

### NOT ABLE TO GET THE ACME CERTIFICATE USING FOR TLS WHOAMI

[my-pain](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/kubernetes-kitchen/blob/master/gcp/task-004-traefik/traefik-2.2/part3-traefik-whoami-lets-encrypt/.ReadMe_images/unsuccessful-output-tls-try.png)

### INFRA Details

- I am using Google Kubernetes Cluster (the one being talked about here -cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine, click on Go to Console).
- Traefik version is 2.2.
- And I am using "CloudShell" to access the cluster".

### ASK:

1) Where am i going wrong to get the TLS Certificate?

2) If its firewall issue how to resolve?

3) If you have any other better example for `Treafik Let's encrypt simplest example on GKE` please let me know

Comment: Could you share more information? You are using GKE or GCP? Which version of apps are you using? On what OS are you running your cluster? Are you using CloudShell or terminal from your machine?

Comment: @PjoterS , I am using Google Kubernetes Cluster (the one being talked about here -https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine,  click on `Go to Console`). Traefik version is 2.2. And I am using "CloudShell" to access the cluster". I have updated the question with much more detailed info, kindly do let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `sudo` before `kubectl port-forward` command. You are trying to bind to privileged ports, so you need more permissions.

It is not the simplest example for GKE, because you could use GKE LoadBalnacer instead of `kubectl port-forward`.

Try with this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 80
      targetPort: web
    - protocol: TCP
      name: websecure
      port: 443
      targetPort: websecure
  selector:
    app: traefik
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Then you can find your new IP with `kubectl get svc` in `EXTERNAL-IP` column, add proper DNS record for your domain and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @FL3SH , I have implemented a similar solution like the one you suggested. I have updated the description of the question to give more details. Still I am not able to get the ACME certificate. Please do let me know where I am going wrong? :(

Comment: Check your GitHub issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FL3SH , I followed you advice. It has partially solved the problem. Now I am getting certificate but its not trusted by the browser. I have shared the logs and relevent screenshots in the ReadMe.md file. Kindly check and let me know if I have done something wrong. [click me](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/kubernetes-kitchen/tree/master/gcp/task-004-traefik/traefik-2.2/part3-traefik-whoami-lets-encrypt)

Comment: Perfect, now comment out [staging](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/kubernetes-kitchen/blob/master/gcp/task-004-traefik/traefik-2.2/part3-traefik-whoami-lets-encrypt/15-traefik-deployment.yaml#L36) CA provider and you are done ;)

Comment: will it give me a trusted certificate :) ? ... will try that as well and share the findings

Comment: thanks a lot. I have the sweet and beautiful certificate now! Behold the beautiful beast with your own eyes ;) [behold](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/kubernetes-kitchen/blob/master/gcp/task-004-traefik/traefik-2.2/part3-traefik-whoami-lets-encrypt/.ReadMe_images/finally-the-cert-needed.png)